# missing ) after argument list when creating a variable right after a for statement

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am trying to create the Bagel game and keep getting missing ) after argument list when I try to create the guess variable right after the for statement. Can someone tell me how to fix this?

```
 alert('Lets play the bagel game! If you can guess my three digit number (with each digit being unique) within 20 turns, then you win! I will only provide you with three hints. Pico, which means one digit is correct, but in the wrong position. Fermi, which means one digit is correct and in the right position. Bagels, which means no digits are correct');
//computer generates number
function numberRange(){
  var number = Math.round(Math.random()*1000);
  var num =number.toString();
  if (number <= 100 || number == 1000){
    numberRange();

}
else if (num[0] == num[1] || num[0] == num[2] || num[1]==num[2]){
  numberRange();
}
else if (number == undefined || num == undefined){
  numberRange();
}else{
 var numSave = JSON.stringify(num);
 sessionStorage.setItem('number',numSave);
}}
numberRange();
var numGet = sessionStorage.getItem('number');
var numUse = JSON.parse(numGet);
//game start
for (i=1;i<21;i++){
  var validNumber = /\d{3}/;
var guess = prompt('Turn ' + i ': Guess a number!');
while (validNumber.test(guess) == false) {
  alert('Put in a three digit number!');
  var guess = prompt('Turn ' + i ': Guess a number!');
}
if (validNumber.test(guess)){
  var guessNum = guess.toString();
   if (guessNum[0] == numUse[0] && guessNum[1] && numUse[1] && guessNum[2] == numUse[2]){
    alert('Congratulations! You win!');
    break
  }
  else if ((guessNum[0] == numUse[0] || guessNum[1] == numUse[1] || guessNum[2] == numUse[2]) && (guessNum[0] == numUse[1] || guessNum[0] == numUse[2] || guessNum[1] == numUse[0] || guessNum[1] == numUse[2] || guessNum[2] == numUse[0] || guessNum[2] == numUse[3])){
    alert('Pico and Fermi!');
  }else if(guessNum[0] == numUse[1] || guessNum[0] == numUse[2] || guessNum[1] == numUse[0] || guessNum[1] == numUse[2] || guessNum[2] == numUse[0] || guessNum[2] == numUse[3]){
    alert('Pico!');
  }else if (guessNum[0] == numUse[0] || guessNum[1] == numUse[1] || guessNum[2] == numUse[2]){
alert('Fermi!');
  }else (guessNum[0] != numUse[0] && guessNum[0] != numUse[1] && guessNum[0] != numUse[2] && guessNum[1] != numUse[0] && guessNum[1] != numUse[1] && guessNum[1] != numUse[2] && guessNum[2] != numUse[0] && guessNum[2] != numUse[1] && guessNum[2] != numUse[2]){
    alert('Begels!');
  }
}
}
```

Comment: You are missing a `+` operator for the string concatenation => `'Turn ' + i ': Guess a number!'`

Comment: thanks so much for the input guys. I'm surprised I didn't match the missing +

Answer (score 0):

I see several issues.

```
var guess = prompt('Turn ' + i ': Guess a number!');
```

is missing + after i '

It should be like this:

```
var guess = prompt('Turn ' + i + ': Guess a number!');
```

You're also defining the same variable name twice inside the for scope, just do `guess = prompt('Turn ' + i ': Guess a number!');` inside the while loop.

I didn't check the rest of the code, but this should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

you seem to have missed a "+" as a part of string concatenation.

```
prompt('Turn ' + i+': Guess a number!');
```

instead of

```
prompt('Turn ' + i': Guess a number!');
```

Answer (score 0):

What the other folks said (there are 2 places you need `+` signs, l#s 25, 28) and your final `else` needs an `if` before the test clause (L# 41).  After that it should at least run. A few other comments:

1. only `var` a variable the first time it is declared.
2. look into `switch` statements and use them when you have more than 2 options and a default.
3. try to break up long lines (as in add line feeds) and keep all the code on the screen. Javascript doesn't care at all about white space so use it. Far easier to debug things when you can see it all.
4. a good editor will find this stuff for you. There are a lot of free ones (Atom, Komodo) that do a decent job of syntax highlighting and error detection.